# Intl.DateTimeFormat returns different results in same browser

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization, intl

I am trying to find out whether user is using 12 hour format or not by his locale.
The function used is `Intl.DateTimeFormat(["kk-KZ"],  { hour: 'numeric' }).resolvedOptions().hourCycle`. I am getting `h12` in Chrome (when I should be getting `h23`), one of my friends is getting `h23`, and the other `h12` as well.
Locale is not something retrived from browser, we have control over it, so different locales being passed is not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: You should either use the `Intl` API to format the hours according to the host settings, or allow your user to configure their preference in your app… but attempting to infer the information will not be productive in the current state of the API.

Comment: @jsejcksn—the host environment doesn't provide any user–specified or default formatting. It might provide language, but that might be overridden by browser settings.